# The closure of irreducible of closed set minus another closed set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I was wondering if the following is true. If I have two closed sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is irreducible. Say we take $C = cl(A - B)$ is it true that because $A$ is irreducible $C = A$?

Comment: What if $A = B$?

Comment: What is the definition of an $irreducible$ closed set?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526147/irreducible-subsets-of-a-topological-space

Answer (score 1):

This is the fact that nonempty open sets in irreducible spaces are dense. In the notation of the question, we have
$$A\supseteq C\cup (B\cap A) \supseteq (A-B)\cup (B\cap A) = A$$
and thus $C\cup (B\cap A) = A$. Now, both $C$ and $B\cap A$ are closed in $A$ while $A$ is irreducible, so
$$C = A\quad\text{or}\quad B \supseteq A$$